# Django - object level premission and class based generic views

Tags: python, django, permissions

This is the model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='cars')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Url pattern goes something like this:

```
url(r'^car/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(CarDetails.as_view()), name='car_details)
```

And view:

```
class CarDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'car'
    template_name = 'my_app/car_details.html'
    model = models.Car

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        car = super(CarDetail, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if car.user != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        else:
            return car
```

This works fine, but in every class I have to override `get_object` to prevent user to mess with someone else's objects. This includes editing and deleting for every model I have and this is serious violation of DRY principle.

Is there a better way to do this? Something like `login_required` decorator maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about definig base class (or mixin) and using inheritance?

```
class CurUserOnlyDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(CurUserOnlyDetailView, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if obj.user != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        else:
            return obj

class CarDetail(CurUserOnlyDetailView):
    context_object_name = 'car'
    template_name = 'my_app/car_details.html'
    model = models.Car

# another view, no DRY violation
class BikeDetail(CurUserOnlyDetailView):
    context_object_name = 'bike'
    template_name = 'my_app/bike_details.html'
    model = models.Bike
```

Comment: Not quite what I needed, but gave me right idea and solved my problem with one little difference. I added clarification to question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was more-or-less simple as DrTyrsa proposed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846884/5446749), with one little difference. I created base class `CurUserOnly` that inherits `object`, instead of `DetailView` (I wanted to use this class with `DeleteView` and `UpdateView`, too) and now `CarDetail` inherits `CurUserOnly` and `DetailView`, `CarDelete` inherits `CurUserOnly` and `DeleteView` and so on...

Funny thing is that I tried this before, but it didn't work because I forgot python's MRO and `DetailView` was first in inheritance list when `CurUserOnly` should be!

In the end, here is `CurUserOnly` class:

```
class CurUserOnly(object):
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(CurUserOnly, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        user_attribute = getattr(self, 'user_attribute', 'user')
        user = obj
        for part in user_attribute.split('.'):
            user = getattr(user, part, None)
        if user != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        else:
            return obj
```

And if I have a model that does not have direct contact to user all I need to do is add `user_attribute` field. For example, if I have model `Tyre` with ForeignKey to `Car` its DeleteView would look like this:

```
class TyreDelete(CurUserOnly, DeleteView):
    model = models.Tyre
    user_attribute = 'car.user'
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7844962/2) to the question [Django - object level premission and class based generic views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844962/django-object-level-premission-and-class-based-generic-views) by the OP [del-boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61363/del-boy) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>